# Android Studio: Bottom Navigation View not showing item in my menu added later time

Tags: android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I had use BottomNavigationView in my activity_main.xml, at first I only put 1 item in my menu, but then later on I added more item in my menu, but it only show the item I added at beginning even if I remove everything in my menu, it still only show the item I put in my menu at beginning. How can I fix this?

I had tried rebuild the whole activity_main.xml and menu.xml, but it still not fixed. Below is my activity_main.xml and menu.xml

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="@string/Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home" />
    <item android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:title="@string/Profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile" />
</menu>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

At beginning I only add **item: Home**, at later time I add my second **item: Profile**, but the navigation view show only Home which I added when the time I build it.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the BottomNavigationView?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal it is just like normal BottomNavigationBar, showing the icon and title, but when I modify item in menu.xml, it doesn't update.

Comment: You are mixing androidx libraries and support libraries. Remove the support libraries and add implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti issue still occur after I changed the implementation, but I realise that I need to resync the project to make it change.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti
Thanks for the reply, after the research I found a line of code in my gradle:
`sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/menu'] } }`
and after I removed this line of code, the issue solved.

Comment: where is the gradle line?

Comment: @MaijiedHasanShuvo inside project's build gradle